# Bootstrap 3 sticky footer reval z-index issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello to all the community

*[Solved] For the sake of readability below are provided the steps*

I'm trying to achieve this result (see the following demo and scroll to the bottom of the page)
http://iainandrew.github.io/footer-reveal/

You'll see the footer that will reveal unveil gets uncovered below the last section

This is the source of this useful script
https://github.com/IainAndrew/footer-reveal

Unfortunately I've tried to find a solution to make it working in a bootstrap 3 basic page (header, main, footer), but looks like there is the need of a trick to make the z-index to work properly.

I've tried hard to find it, but now I'm in loop so I'm surely too blind to see it :-) even if it would stand in front of me :-)

[This is my test page](http://www.assistenza-tecnica-informatica.it/initia/)

as you can see, the footer is on top of the content despite it is z-index value -101.

[image]

Can you kindly help to make it work?

Thank you

[Solution]
The main issue was caused by the absence of a background in the main and missing container
So I've

1. added one div I've called *wrapper*
2. the *wrapper* div starts right after the body tag and closes right before the footer
3. I gave the *wrapper* a solid white #FFF background

this allows this nice script to work with bootstrap 3 and jquery 2 providing a nice **slide out sticky footer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to give a `background` to your container:

```
.container {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works but partially, I've set a div container with some background. Now the point is the margin-bottom. In the footer-reveal script there is a dynamic update for some others properties but nothing involves the margin-bottom... which looks really needed with bootstrap, since now that works (see again my test page) it doesn't uncover properly and for responsiveness it needs to be adjusted in relation with the real footer height. As minor behavior, the shadow doesn't appear.

Comment: Remove width: 0 from your footer and add a little padding, say padding: 20px to it.

Comment: Hello Tarun, as you may see on the screenshot above, I don't have width:0 it has width:1170. I can add the padding, yes. But now that I've studied the footer-reveal script, I do notice that on load and on resize the script sets/changes the margin-bottom of the prev.css element. and now it doesn't work properly and so it doesn't work properly with a container :-(.

Comment: In your test page, it is 0.

Comment: Thank you Tarun for replying and helping. The width is set dynamically by the footer-reveal script, see it in the screenshot on top of this page, you can see its value is 1170 and it is in the "element" (elemento) section. You see it also in the section that I have highlighted in the html panel.

Comment: Ok, so is there still any issue that you are facing?

Comment: Yes, currently the issues are two. To make it work I had to add a container section I've called it "wrapper", but the script sets the margin-bottom to a prev.css so now with the div that wraps everything it doesn't sets the margin-bottom correctly to the right element. Second issue is the shadow (on top of this page there is a link to a working properly demo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100836/discussion-between-robert-and-tarun-dugar).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've set the wrapper correctly now. It was needed to close it before than the footer :-| my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have it working fine. The problem is that your `content` is see-through. Give your content a background color and change display to block, and you will see the effect.

```
content{
    background-color: orange;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Done the change. Also it was not needed, since bootstrap css already sets the footer as display:block. It doesn't work. Please note that the footer must stay behind the content and if you watch the working demo (first link in my post), when scrolling the page, you reach the bottom, the footer must "slide" out below the content.

Comment: Hello null05, your hint was correct about the background color, instead about the margin bottom is already and dynamically provided by the script that sets and updates the margin-bottom.